# what is the most efficient way to extract rows from one CSV file using input from another CSV file

Tags: java, csv

I have two CSV files `input1.txt` and `input2.txt`. I need to take one value from `input1.txt` and search for it in `input2.txt` and if it is found, write the entire record from `input2.txt` to another file.

I have written the below code and it is working but it is very slow. Is there any more efficient way to achieve this?

```
import java.io.*;

public class FileCompare
{
    private static final EOL = System.getProperty("line.separator");

    public static void main(String args[])
        throws IOException
    {
        FileReader in = null;
        FileReader comp = null;
        FileWriter out = null;
        FileWriter out2 = null;

        try {
            in = new FileReader("input1.txt");  //file containing value to search
            out = new FileWriter("matching.txt"); // file to write output
            out2 = new FileWriter("notfound.txt"); // file to write non matching
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(in);      
            String p, q;
            boolean done;

            // Read the input file line by line
            while ((p = br.readLine()) != null) {
                done = false;
                String str = p;
                String delims = "[\\t]"; 
                String[] tokens = str.split(delims);

                Long acno = Long.parseLong(tokens[5]);  // value in input1.txt  to be checked against input2.txt
                Long si = Long.parseLong(tokens[31]);

                comp = new FileReader ("input2.txt");  // file containing  bulk data  
                BufferedReader bbr = new BufferedReader (comp); // opening bulk file 

                while (!done) {  // flag to break the second file operation if matching value found
                    while ((q = bbr.readLine()) != null) {  // loop to read bulk file 
                        String delim2 = "[\\t]"; 
                        String[] token2 = q.split(delim2); // splitting file based on delimiter
                        Long acno1 = Long.parseLong(token2[5]);
                        Long si1 = Long.parseLong(token2[31]);

                        if (acno1.equals(acno)) {  // checking the condition 
                            out.write(q + EOL); // writing the matching entry(entire row) from input2.txt
                            done = true;  // changing the flag value , so that control will go to input file for next line
                            break;  // breaking the bulk reading loop , because we got the value as per condition
                        } else {  // if condition not satisfies 
                            out2.write(p + EOL);  //writing entry input1.txt if it is not matching
                            done = true;  //  flag value changing , so that control will go to input file for next
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } finally {
            if (in != null) in.close();
            if (out != null) out.close();
            if (out2 != null) out2.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: if input2 is not too big, store it in memory - that will save a lot of time. Then, step 2, use a Map structure to do your matching and you will save even more time.

Comment: Hint: for working code, turn to codereview.stackexchange.com ... and please: improve the formatting. You expect us to read your 50+ lines of code, understand it, fix its performance problem; and you don't even find the time to use the "preview" to ensure your source code is formatted for human reading? And you know: from a "code quality" input, your code is pretty much horrible. So much code in one method, doing so many things basically violates anything that makes code "easy to read". And surprise: code that is hard to read, is also hard to maintain, rework, extend, fix.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: If `input2` is too long to fit in memory, create an index - a mapping between the `acno` to the line numbers that match it. Essentially, you're going to need a database with indexes, whether you use an existing one or create a simple implementation yourself.

Comment: @GhostCat Just because the program works doesn't necessarily mean that [it needs to be migrated to codereview](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300981/performance-question-stack-overflow-or-code-review)...

Comment: You are not responding to requests for more information, so I am voting to close. The short answer is, if you can extract the information out of `input1,txt` and keep it in memory, you should do that. If you can't, then your current approach will have to suffice.

Comment: Sorry ,  I was away from my system for some time . I saw the reviews and answers .  Sorry , this is my first post in this forum ,  may be I did a crude formatting ,  will correct next time .  I will  check some of the options provided .    Also  using a DB  is not practical since my  input files are too big and this activity is very adhoc in nature.

Comment: @SeanBright  -   Thanks for the support ,  ( I think you edited my code - sorry  ,  I am learning this forum and its behaviour)   I will check this .

Comment: @ghostCat - Thanks to your input also , will take care next time.